# Org mode export filter for latex backend to create \cmidrule

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am trying to write a LaTeX export filter that should replace all table rows with cells having entries such as `<3cid4> by \cmidrule{lr}{3-4}`

The idea is to have a table row of this kind

```
| <2cid3> |           <4cid5> |        <6cid7>             |                   |                                           |                   |                   |
```

Which should be exported to

```
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
```

This is as far as I have gone.

```
(defun org-export-cmidrule-filter-latex (row backend info)
  (while (string-match "\\(<\\([0-9]+\\)cid\\([0-9]+\\)?>[[:blank:]]*\\([^&]+\\)\\)" row)
    (let ((start (string-to-number (match-string 2 row)))
          (end (or (match-string 3 row) "l")))
      (setq row (replace-match (format "\\\\cmidrule(lr){%s-%s}" start end) nil nil row 1))
      (while (string-match "& \\| \\\\\\\\" row 0)
        (setq row (replace-match "" nil nil row))
        (decf start))))
  row)

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-table-row-functions
         'org-export-cmidrule-filter-latex)
```

The above filter works if I have only one or two `<[0-9]cid[0-9]>` strings in a row. It does not pick up the third `<[0-9]cid[0-9]>` string.

The problem seems to be in this part of the code:

```
(while (string-match "& \\| \\\\\\\\" row 0)
  (setq row (replace-match "" nil nil row))
  (decf start))
```

If I comment it out, I get three `\cmidrule` latex commands, but with `&s` and `\\`

Somehow, the above lines replace more than just `&s` and `\\`.

Would much appreciate if anyone could help improve this filter.

Comment: To which filter variable do you add this function?

Comment: To org-export-filter-table-row-functions. Edited the original post to include the corresponding commands.